# Dygraph Millisecond Plotting

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am attempting to use the R dygraphs package to produce millisecond plotting.
The example I'm following is at 
https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/issues/46

The exact code is

```
require(dygraphs); require(xts); require(htmlwidgets);
CustomAxisLabel <- 'function (d, gran) {
                          return Dygraph.zeropad(d.getHours()) + ":" + 
                                 Dygraph.zeropad(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + 
                                 Dygraph.zeropad(d.getSeconds()) + "." + 
                                 Dygraph.zeropad(d.getMilliseconds());
                         }'
CustomValueFormat = 'function (ms) {
                          var d = new Date(ms);
                          return Dygraph.zeropad(d.getHours()) + ":" + 
                          Dygraph.zeropad(d.getMinutes()) + ":" + 
                          Dygraph.zeropad(d.getSeconds()) + "." + 
                          Dygraph.zeropad(d.getMilliseconds());
                         }'


len <- 60 * 60  + 10
RDData <- xts(runif(len,0,1), seq(as.POSIXct("2015-04-01 10:00:00"),  
                              as.POSIXct("2015-04-02 15:00:00"), length = len),tz="GMT")
dygraph(RDData) %>%  
         dyOptions(useDataTimezone = TRUE) %>% 
         dyAxis("x",axisLabelFormatter =JS(CustomAxisLabel),valueFormatter=JS(CustomValueFormat),ticker="Dygraph.dateTicker")
```

Unfortunately, I can't get this to work - I assume its an issue with the CustomValueFormat but I can't find where.

Comment: You don't seem to have followed the suggestions in that discussion. You also fail to provide the needed library/require-calls.

Comment: Thanks for the edits BondedDust. As mentioned in the github link the JS() call is not strictly necessary but I've included the htmlwidgets library for clarity. Furthermore, it is suggested to review the JavaScript console for errors but I can not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

These changes make it show a plot for me:

- remove duplicate " in the 4th line
- add ticker="Dygraph.dateTicker" to last line (dyAxis call)

However, even with these changes, the plot appears to ignore fractional seconds. I tried adding options(digits.secs=3) near beginning, and this did not help either.

Comment: That you for the suggestions, they have been incorporated into the original question. Unfortunately, I have not found a solution to this problem - any help from other users would be appreciated.